# ViewPagerAdapter Attempt to invoke virtual method Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I tried to create image slider with ViewPager and i think i got trouble in  ViewPagerAdapter.java . I still newbie about android studio and i need help.

Here's the code

### Error Message

> 11-25 16:53:16.683 24857-24857/com.labs.penjualan.project.penjualan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.labs.penjualan.project.penjualan, PID: 24857
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at com.labs.penjualan.project.penjualan.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.java:38)

## ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.labs.penjualan.project.penjualan;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer [] images = {R.drawable.s1,R.drawable.s2,R.drawable.s3};

//    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
//        this.context = context;
//    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(HomeFragment homeFragment) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // I THINK THIS LINE ERROR
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a NullPointerException because there is no `Context`, the `context` field points to nothing, to null!

That's because you **commented the constructor** where you got a `Context` from the arguments and set it to your field. You replaced it with HomeFragment, yet HomeFragment is not a context (and you don't use it somewhere in the code).

So uncomment the previous constructor to use the Context.

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```